# el evento Tabchange del accordion panel de primefaces no funciona

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo un `accordionPanel` creado dinámicamente y deseo obtener el identificador de la Tab que activa el usuario, para esto estoy haciendo uso del único evento [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) que se puede aplicar a los acordeones (`tabChange`), sin embargo este nunca es invocado.

Aquí esta mi archivo xhtml

```
<p:accordionPanel id="equipos" dynamic="true" activeIndex="null"
    value="#{equipoBean.equipoDecoradoList}" var="equipoDecorado">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{equipoBean.onChange}" />
    <p:tab title="#{equipoDecorado.equipo.nombre}" id="tab">

    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

y este es el metodo en el Backing Bean

```
public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event){
    System.out.println("omchnage");
}
```

Pero cada vez que yo selecciono una Tab no se llama el método,

Les estaría muy agradecidos si pueden decirme que esta mal o que me hace falta.

Comment: Es extraño. Yo he probado eso con PrimeFaces 5.3 y funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Luiggi Mendoza tenia razon, con la version 5.3 de primefaces funciona sin ningun problema, al parecer la version 5.0 presenta problemas con esta funcionalidad.